# Getting error on running flask: TypeError: get() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python-2.7, api, flask

Here's the code:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__ name__)

api = Api(app)


class Hello(Resource):

    def get(self, name):
        return {'Hello': name}


api.add_resource(Hello, '/hello/')

if __ name__ == '__ main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Error Traceback:**

> TypeError TypeError: get() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Please rephrase your question and modify the title of your question. Don't ask your question in the title. And try to use some `code` formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: edit `api.add_resource(Hello, '/hello/<string:name>')`

Comment: @waynetech it worked. Thanks!